# Ember.js : Error while processing route: route._stashNames is not a function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js

I've been working to incorporate Ember.js in an existing Ruby on Rails Web application. As expected, Ember.js recognizes the URLs of the backend and puts the datas in the store. I did fetch the datas from the server using a namespace and resource, as shown by Ember Inspector.

Disclaimer : I am fairly new to Ember.js and I have to incorporate it in an existing app. My code might be completely wrong but it sends back the wanted datas from the server, so it has to be good in a way.

However, I keep getting this error in console even though the fetching was successful and I can't find anything related to it on the internet :

Error while processing route: list route._stashNames is not a function

Here is my code :

Adapter :

```
App.ListAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend();

App.ListAdapter.reopen({

    namespace:'conversations/simon.t@kimoby.com/'

});
```

Resource :

```
App.Router.map(function(){

    this.resource('list', { path : '/'});

});
```

Routing :

```
App.ListRoute = Ember.Router.extend({

    model: function(){

    return this.store.filter('list', { status : "opened"}, function(){ return true; });
    },

});
```

Model:

```
App.List = DS.Model.extend({

    readStatus: DS.attr('string'),
    status: DS.attr('string'),
    timeAgoElement: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

XHR response and console error :
http://gyazo.com/3cc140f476f24892cf6902f4020ee29f

Ember inspector shows the datas :
http://gyazo.com/9c6f05df2f0840e1813f187c63ec3572

So my question is, where am I wrong? The method route._stashNames is located in ember.js but that doesn't indicate me anything.

Thank you.

Comment: What version of Ember/Ember Data, here's a jsbin where you should be able to reproduce with minimal code and a copy of your json.  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/savocadane/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Resolved. I wrote Ember.Router.extend instead of Ember.Route.extend

Comment: That's really funny, that was like my first SO ember question ;)